# Nodejs - parse response data without parsing as String?

Tags: node.js

I'm following some tutorials online, and I'm trying to parse a response from an HTTP post call from my node app.  My app acts as an interceptor, we make a POST request to the interceptor app, I transform the data, then I post it to another client to perform some action, and then I want to return the response from the other app as my app's response.  Below is the code I use to make the post:

```
const request = http.request(options, function(response) {
 console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
 console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
 response.setEncoding('utf8');
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
   console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
   //res is the actual response object to my app's own post function
   res.status(response.statusCode).send({response:chunk});
 });
});
```

Now, the response to the post object looks like `["Hey there! How can I help you?"]`.

However, when I return that as a response to my API, the body looks like:

`"response": "[\"I am doing well. Thank you for asking.\"]\n"`.

I want to interact with the array that is returned, grab the string at index 0, and return that as my response.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
res.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
res.status(response.statusCode).send(chunk);
```

Comment: hey, that did it! Though I guess I have a question after that then.  The data appears to come back to the node js as an array string, but I just want to return the string itself.  Do I need to parse the string as an array somehow and then grab the first index?

Comment: Try res.status(response.statusCode).send({response:chunk});